# Counter part of Add Lateral (Water Utility) in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, arcgis-water-utilities

I am trying to practice ArcGIS Pro. In ArcMap I usually use Add Lateral in Water Utility Network to basically just add perpendicular lines from a point to a line. I'm not using geometric network. My main goal is just to add a line.

Now, I am trying to recreate this process in ArcGIS Pro yet I wasn't able to find a quick process to make this done with a click of a button just like Add Lateral in Water Utility Network.

I read that we can use UTILITY NETWORK yet I have no knowledge as of this moment to set this up.

Is there a better way or the only solution is Utility Network? I only need the line. No attributes/Connection/Relation needed,etc. Just the line feature.

Comment: Have you tried contacting esri to see what they say? May be there is no equivalence or they are calling it something else?

Answer (score 0):

Edit>Create and create a new line feature. If you are adding that feature to an existing feature class for your laterals, select that feature class in the "templates" section on the create features dialog box.

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/editing/get-started-editing.htm

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. I think the steps that you mentioned is the manual way of creating laterals. In arcmap using water utility tools, you can select all the points then just click "add lateral" and it will automatically create all the lateral lines for you. I am finding the same tool in arcgis pro yet I cant find an alternative. I think water utility was removed in arcgis pro?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I misunderstood your question. It seems likely that they just haven't ported that tool over to arcGIS pro yet - I am not seeing it in any of my pro searches or toolboxes.